CDP commands of Page domain are not working
I have opened a remote debugging port on the Chrome. With PostMan I have connected to the CDP websocket and sending some commads but most of the commands except Target domain are throwing with message like
Request :
{
    "id":1,
    "method":"Network.enable",
    "params":{
        "maxTotalBufferSize" :4096
    }
}

Resposne :
{"code":-32601,"message":"'Network.enable' wasn't found"}

I have tried commands of multiple domanis like Page,Network etc but all are throwing error like respective commands not found.I have tried adding sessionId also like but still not working nd throwing session id is invalid.
{    "id":1,    "sessionId":<sessionid received from Target Attachment command>    "method":"Network.enable",    "params":{        "maxTotalBufferSize" :4096    }}

Why it is not working?
Are there any settings I have missed?

How specifically did you connect to CDP socket? You probably used the wrong endpoint and connected to the browser and not to the page.

Example endpoint I connected is "ws://127.0.0.1:50508/devtools/browser/e5d486e4-1621-4350-b515-efe0dbde1b82". Am I connecting to wrong endpoint?
Does I have to use "page" instead of "broswer" in the above endpoint?

Yes your comment gave me a hint and it worked.Does "Page.navigate" and opening url manually in a tab in browser are both same? beacuse when I am calling an url using "Page.navigate" in the network I could not see any call initiated by "js" files apart from tha of chrome.

Your endpoint is for the browser itself as indicated by the word browser. The documentation describes how to obtain page endpoints at the end.

Thanks for the great info. I missed these things. And I when I open a page in browser let say there are 50 requests but when I open the same page using "Pgae.navigate" or "Target.createtarget" the number of requests count is less. On high level I could see some requests which are originated by JS are not called. Is it exepected behavior or is there any other way?

I don't know. It may be a bug.
